# Is it safe to mark a postgres function as parallel safe if its uses `set local`

Tags: postgresql

I'm using something like this as part of a query in my application in order to authenticate users

```sql
set local jwt.claims.sub to 'ffad81a1-cc4e-4370-b4bc-1453975a4e8d';
```

With the above is it safe to access that value in another procedure that is marked as `parallel safe`

I'm executing a transaction which first makes the `set local` call, then performs a `select` query. The function that I want to mark as parallel safe is actually used as part of my *row level security* logic, so it executes during the `select` query and all within the same transaction that started with the `set local` call.

The documentation states

> ... should be labeled as parallel restricted if they access temporary tables, client connection state, cursors, prepared statements, or miscellaneous backend-local state which the system cannot synchronize in parallel mode (e.g., setseed cannot be executed other than by the group leader because a change made by another process would not be reflected in the leader).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createfunction.html

I'm wondering if this use of `set local` is considered as `client connection state`?  Hopefully not as `parallel safe` is making a dramatic difference for some functions and would love to enable it

Comment: I don't think it's safe to mark it as `parallel safe`  in that case. You should make that value a parameter of the function, then you can mark the function as `parallel safe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function that uses `SET` or `SET LOCAL` should be marked `PARALLEL RESTRICTED`, otherwise the worker processes that work on the query don't agree on the setting, which can lead to trouble.

You could refactor your code and run `SET LOCAL` outside the function, *before* you run the SQL statement that uses the function. As long as they run in the same transaction, it shouldn't make a difference.

Alternatively, you can use

```
ALTER FUNCTION ... SET parameter = value;
```

In that case, the changed parameter value is only in effect during function execution and does not leak out of the function, so it should be safe to use `PARALLEL SAFE`.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe.  I've updated my original question to better explain my scenario;  I'm executing a transaction which first makes the set local call, then performs a select query. The function that I want to mark as parallel safe is actually used as part of my row level security logic, so it executes during the select query and all within the same transaction that started with the set local call.  It sounds like this RLS function is safe to mark as `parallel safe` based on your answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand your explanation. My answer remains: Do the `SET LOCAL` in a different SQL statement than the query you want to parallelize.